# Matching users Firestore db model

Tags: firebase, nosql, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am developing a mobile app in flutter to help people connect with DIY experts.

The app will connect people who need advice to people who are expert, then let them chat in 1:1 messaging. As example, person A want advice on plumbing, so the app connect him to person B, who know how to plumbing.

My database model is use Firestore to store user details and FCM tokens. Cloud functions to send notifications to all expert FCM tokens (to notify them when non-expert need help).

Here my model so far:

1. Firestore: Store 2 groups users: non-expert and expert.
2. When non-expert in app taps ‘I need help!’, flag non-expert’s field in database ’needhelp’ to set to true.
3. Firebase Cloud function listen to change, and send FCM to all expert FCM tokens in database.
4. ?? When one expert in app tap ‘I can help!’, create new chat document in db ??
5. Firestore: Create new Messages document, store messages etc.

**My question is step 4: how to match and connect expert and non-expert in new 1:1 chat when expert tap ‘I can help’ in client app. On tap, should expert client app set new value in document in Firestore? What document? What db model for this?**

Similar apps are dating apps e.g. Tinder. Fun question: What would Tinder Firestore look like? :)

Comment: So you basically need a database schema for your app, right?

Comment: Yes basically @AlexMamo. I have watch you youtube videos!! But I no find how to match users at step 4 above.

Comment: You can find answers for all your questions in my tutorials. For a one to one chat app, please see this **[Firestore chat tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0Ak1HiH0tTPTJXsOEy-5v9qb)**.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have watch all you videos, but not answer my question. You schema work where you always know exactly who you will connect with. In you video: 'Second User' / First Random User' / 'Second Random User'. You schema work for normal chat app because always know who need connect to. However in my app we never know which users we will be connecting before there is match. We don't know who non-expert will connect to. We don't even know if non-expert will find match. So my database model must be different.

Comment: Once you change that property to available, it means that you know the person you are chating with. So basically the whole problem is reduces the schema in my video.

Comment: @alexmamo Good point! So base on you schema you suggest to have: ‘users', ‘rooms’, ‘messages’ root-level collections. Store users as documents (document name == Firebase auth UID). User fields: chatroom, UID, username and ‘needhelp’ boolean. My app no need contacts because match for one-time only 1:1 chat. What you think?

Comment: @AlexMamo Second question. You video #4 have ‘rooms’ and ‘messages’ root collection. I think my app need only ‘messages’. Because user never have more than one chat open in app and only 1:1. After users finish chat they will never look at it again. The next chat will be with different person and no need to view previous chats. You agree?

Comment: First comment, yes, it's a possible database structure.For the first comment, according to your app use-case, yes, you can model with or without it.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thanks! What you think about my second question?

Comment: The second respons was actually for the second question.

Comment: @AlexMamo I have now make most my Firestore db! My final design is have separate collection for non-expert needing help. This collection store document (document name = non-expert UID). Field is the chatroom name (random string). When expert tap ‘I can help!’ then app retrieve chatID from this document. Then find chat ID in ‘rooms’ collection and load data. What you think? Thanks for help!

Comment: I think it might work. If you want more informations post a new question regarding that schema.

Comment: Thanks! I have post here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53746920

Answer (score 0):

create chat rooms that go like: chatroom1, chatroom2, chatroom 3 .....

if a user wants to join chatroom1 should be empty so he will join this one.

a second user wants to join and founds 1 user in chat room 1 so he joins the room and they start chatting

a third user comes by and finds that chat room 1 is full (2 people in it) so he joins chat room2 and waits for somebody else to join a nd the pattern goes on............